# Entity Framework - Sorting Strings is causing "The wait operation timed out"

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have the following query that is causing "The wait operation timed out" when I use sorting by `Name`. How can I make it faster? There are 8.5k rows in the `Foods` table.

```
Expression<Func<Food, string>> byName = x => x.FoodTranslations.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Language.Code == CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name).Name;
Expression<Func<Food, string>> byUdsa = x => x.Udsa;

var query = this.DbContext.Foods
            .Where(x => category == null || x.FoodTypeId == category)
            .Where(x => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || x.FoodTranslations.FirstOrDefault(y=>CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name == y.Language.Code).Name.Contains(name)));

        switch (order)
        {
            case 1:
                query = query.OrderBy(byUdsa);
                break;
            default:
                query = query.OrderBy(byName);
                break;
        }

        var result = new JsonFoodIndexResult();
        result.Foods = query.Skip(start)
            .Take(size)
            .Select(x => new JsonFoodIndex
            {
                Name = x.FoodTranslations.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Language.Code == CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name).Name,
                Id = x.Id,
                Udsa = x.Udsa,
                Category = x.FoodType.FoodTypeTranslations.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Language.Code == CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name).Name
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
query = query.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(byName);
```

Entity framework creates Proxy objects to track changes for each record that is ever retrieved & this creation takes a lot of time.Since,while retreiving, we do not need tracking,you can set it as Off as shown above.